# How to expand an exponential number in PHP?

Tags: php, math

How do I expand a number represented by 1.8E-7 to the actual number in PHP?

I am using CakePHP 3.x, and litecoind, and for some reason litecoind is returning the balance as 1.8E-7

For example, I would like to run a native php function...

```
 expand_exponential_number('1.8E-7')
```

and have it return

```
 0.00000018
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [`number_format ( float $number [, int $decimals = 0 ] )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

```
<?php
echo number_format(1.8e-7, 8); // 0.00000018
```

https://3v4l.org/8SSsN

Answer (score 3):

1.8E-7 *is* a number. It's 0.00000018 represented in scientific notation.

If you want the number represented "normally", you can use `sprintf()` with the `%f` format, e.g.

```
sprintf("%.10f", 1.8e-7)
=> 0.000000180000
```

Note that the "10" is the number of decimal places that will be used; you'll need to increase this if you need numbers smaller than 10<sup>-10</sup>.